# Remove the Underline from text inside a div where the div is enclosed in <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently formatting alongside using jquery UI. I have a div that has the "ui-state-error" class and the text within it has the "ui-state-error-text" class. Here is my code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
     <a href="http://www.mobilehealtherecords.com/blog/news-announce/2014/06/faq-
     page/" target="_newtab" style="font-decoration: none">
          <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" id="questionAlert" style=
          "margin: auto">
               <p class="ui-state-error-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" 
               style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span><span style="
               color: font-weight: bold">Alert:</span> The "questions" page has
               been permanently removed. Click here for more information.</p>
          </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

I don't want to list all the different resources I am using, so I am including a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mherPresident/JmyyA/). What I am trying to do is eliminate that annoying blue underline. If you notice I have already tried to remove it from the  tag by inserting a Style with text-decoration: none.

Comment: Just a _small_ typo. You used `font-decoration` in the `style` attribute when it should've been `text-decoration`. `<a href="http://www.mobilehealtherecords.com/blog/news-announce/2014/06/faq-page/" target="_newtab" style="text-decoration: none">` should do the trick.

Comment: is it possible in HTML 5 to have block tags inside inline tags? I remember in xHTML this is not allowed.

Comment: That was exactly what worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle and removed jQuery UI references for simplicity.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmyyA/1/)

Just added the following CSS rule

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I just saw that you had `style="font-decoration: none"`, simply change it for `style="text-decoration: none"`.

Comment: Yes the text-decoration is solution